# Dumping a Flash Memory from a Router with C

Tags: c, serial-port, hex, router, termios

I am creating an application which dumps a router's Flash Memory (similar to brn-tool). The router's flash memory can be dumped from it's boot loader which I already can access via the Serial cable.

The created application so far can grab 10000 bytes ( the maximum bytes that the boot loader returns in one sweep ).

I am having trouble getting the rest of the flash memory bytes.

As mentioned previously the bytes can be read from the boot loader menu by choosing the respective option and entering the amount of bytes to be read. The code is as follows.

```
int ReturnByte(int FileDescriptor, char * StartAddress)
{

// Create the Variable to hold the Start Address in Hexadecimal Notation

char ModdedStartAddress[10];

// Convert the Decimal Input to Hexadecimal

sprintf(ModdedStartAddress,"%X", (unsigned int)strtol(StartAddress, NULL, 10));

// Append a \r to simulate an Enter Press

ModdedStartAddress[strlen(ModdedStartAddress)] = '\r';

 // Go inside the Read Menu

char Character = 'R';

write(FileDescriptor, &Character, 1);   

// Input the Starting Read Address

write(FileDescriptor,ModdedStartAddress, sizeof(ModdedStartAddress ) - 1);  

// Set the Data Length to 1 Byte

Character = '3';

write(FileDescriptor, &Character, 1);   

// Set the Read Count to 10000

write(FileDescriptor, "10000\r", sizeof("10000"));

return 10000;


}
```

When run once, The method works fine and outputs the 10000 bytes correctly.

However in order to create a full Flash Dump, the above method must be run multiple times with different start address. When the method is run multiple times, the Sequence for the menu etc. are not executed when inside the prompt, instead running while the memory data is being returned by the device.

An overview of how the menu works is as follows:

```
Read Menu (Option R)
    Start Address to Read
    Data Length (Set to 3 for 1 Byte)
    Read Count (Set to a maximum of 10000)
        *The Router starts outputting a hex dump*
Back to Menu
```

I am trying to find out weather there is a way to check that all data has been sent from the serial port, in order to re-run the method.

I am using the termios library to connect with the serial port.

Thank you,
Andrew Borg

Comment: Router have specific flash memory size. Therefore, you can guess the maximum size eg. Sercomm H300s has 1GB flash memory. You'll need to crack open some routers, detect the flash memory chip via its writing and then look for datasheet. In it the maximum size is recorded.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure im getting your question correct, but i'll try give it a go.

If you ask for a specific length/size of data ( Read count (menu option) ), so when your program stop getting a stream of bytes, you simply count the bytes you program got, and compare it with the number of bytes you asked for again your Read count.

Hope i helps, if im all wrong, please let me know ! ;)

Comment: The problem I am having is that the application resends the get memory bytes sequence before all bytes are sent by the router.

Comment: Hi again.
Can you upload all of your source code to pastebin or another site like that? It would be easier for me/us to handle your problem.